# Magento: programmatically subscribe user to mailchimp list using mailchimp module

Tags: magento, mailchimp

I have a magento 1.9.1.0 site with MailChimp 1.1.10 installed.

I've already configured the MailChimp module and selected the list I want new subscribers to go into.

What I now want to do is to add customers who placed a successful order to a different mailing list in MailChimp only (so they should not be added as subscribers to magento newsletter). And I'd like to do this using all of the methods provided by the MailChimp module that's installed.

So far I've created a custom module with an observer method that is fired on the`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event.

From here I am not sure what exactly to place in the method. But the basic idea is as follow:

```
public function syncCustomerOnSuccess($observer) {
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

    // Get customer details (fname, lname, email)
    // Make sure customer does not exist in mailchimp mailing list
    // Add customer to mailing list
}
```

If someone could please point me in the right direction.

Comment: `$customer->getData()` to see customer parameters available to you. For MailChimp docs: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/

Comment: @JonathanEltgroth Thanks for the feedback, but I want to try and make use of the MailChimp modules' existing methods to add the subscribers. So my module is dependant on the MailChimp module since it will make use of its methods. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Doesn't the mailchimp docs have anything on the mailchimp module? What you're asking, logically, is not difficult.  I've done a similar thing using a combination of basic Magento methods and methods available in a custom module for CampaignManager.  Basically, you want this: `if (!$mailchimp->findCustomer($customerData....)) { $mailChimp->addCustomer($customerData) } `  You just need to find what methods the mailChimp module provides for you to do this.

Comment: From what I could tell after going through some of the code they only bulk import the magento subscribers. So I ended up using the mailchimp api as I was out of time.

I'll leave this open for a while longer though as I would still like to know how to do this.

Thanks for your comments thus far.